# Generator of End(V)

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

If V is a finite-dimensional vector space of dimension n and G⊂End(V) such that G generates End(V) meaning that any element of End(V) is expressible as a linear combination of products of a number of elements of G, what is the minimal possible number of elements in G?

Comment: The naive lower bound is $n^2$. Wonder if this bound is realizable.

Comment: Check out the edit to my answer for an explicit family of examples.

Comment: Remark: if $n\geq 2$, the minimal number of generators is $\geq 2$ due to Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: @julien would you please specify how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burnside's irreducibility criterion states that an action of a group on a vector space (over an algebraically closed field) is irreducible if and only if the image generates $End(V),$ as you describe. Now, since every finite simple group is generated by two elements, the answer is $2,$ at least for an algebraically closed field.

In fact, if you look at [this Mathematica file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/87nfdex2ppepyoi/SLngens.nb) you will find small generating sets of $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ and $Sp(n, \mathbb{Z}).$ Since the two groups obviously act irreducibly, you have (algebra) generating sets of $M^{n\times n}$ with two or three elements.

Comment: Wow, ok. I'm not sure I understand how you conclude, do you mean that there exists simple groups that have irreducible representations in $\mathrm{End}(V)$? Can you give an example of two matrices that generate $M_k(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Well, simple groups have irreducible representations (of arbitrary dimensions, if you take a big enough simple group). So, take the two generators of your simple group and look at their images under the irrep. I don't have them handy right now...

Comment: @Seub see the edit.

Comment: Thanks. I also had another idea: take two permutation matrices such that the two associated permutations generate the alternating group. I think that works (?)

Comment: @Seub yes, that should work too...

Comment: +1, Igor. @Seub For a concrete example: take any two diagonalizable matrices with one-dimensional eigenspaces and no common (nonzero) eigenvectors. Then every common invariant subspace must be trivial, so Burnside applies ([here is](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/evans/Lomonosov_Rosenthal_04.pdf) a proof of Burnside by two well-known invariant subspace specialists).